# Better message [error page] for laravel in production enviroment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Finally I've pushed my project in live server. I've set

`APP_ENV=production`
`APP_DEBUG=false`

But there are still errors coming in it and displays `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` message. I've made `404`,`500`,`503` error pages. Is there a better way to display what is causing error without changing `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object` is not a server error. You need to capture these in your application yourself.

Comment: Did you tried by clearing config cache ?

Answer (score 1):

All the errors are logged to `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` even with `APP_DEBUG=false`.